# Why doesn't xlwings install correctly on Mac OS 10.7.5?

Tags: python-2.7, osx-lion, xlwings

Here's most of the error message. (Here are some more word just to see if a can get Stack Overflow the accept my question.)

```
bash-3.2$ pip install xlwings
Collecting xlwings
  Using cached xlwings-0.3.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: psutil, appscript, xlwings
  Found existing installation: psutil 0.4.1
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (psutil) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Not uninstalling psutil at /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages, outside environment /Users/schulist/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User
  Running setup.py install for psutil
Complete output from command     psutil/_psutil_osx.c:1635: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘CFDictionaryGetValue’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Can't roll back psutil; was not uninstalled
Command "/Users/schulist/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/yr/zbxgljhx6lxb0hwn66w4t3jw0000gp/T/pip-build-a4Q7fB/psutil/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/yr/zbxgljhx6lxb0hwn66w4t3jw0000gp/T/pip-JDRpLz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/schulist/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/include/site/python2.7/psutil" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/yr/zbxgljhx6lxb0hwn66w4t3jw0000gp/T/pip-build-a4Q7fB/psutil
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue there with upgrading `psutil`, a dependency of `xlwings` on Mac. Since you seem to be using Canopy, you should be able to install xlwings usings their own [packages](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/) and it should properly take care of the dependencies.

Other than that, just upgrading `psutil` first should probably enable you to install `xlwings` via pip again.